# OnTaskRemoved in Android O

Tags: android, xamarin, service, android-8.1-oreo, jobservice

In my android app, I have a `Service` that starts when the app goes in background. `OnStartCommand` begins long running task that analyzes and checks device and app status.

Now, I am preparing the app for Android O. First issue that i faced is `Services`, I rework them to `JobServices`.

Now I am facing another issue. When user removes my app from application stack `JobService.OnTaskRemoved` doesn't get called.

Before, when I used `Service` calling of `Service.OnTaskRemoved` worked fine for me.

Now I see only way. I need My old `Service` for handling`Service.OnTaskRemoved` and new `JobServices` for executing task.

Am I wrong? May be some one can give me good advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are implementing the wrong concepts.., which creates problem.., To tackle it .. you are again implementing wrong things.. Please offload all...

> In my android app, I have a Service that starts when the app goes in background..

### The Problem ;

1. In android O there is no background execution allowed at all.. Even a single line of code is not guaranteed to execute..!!
2. And you want it to execute long running service..!!

### The Solution;

The same service can be started whenever App is opened first time... On acquiring all runtime permissions. As :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
{
     context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, YourLongRunningService.class));
}
else
{
     context.startService(new Intent(context, YourLongRunningService.class));
}
```

> `OnStartCommand` begins long running task that analyzes and checks device and app status.

### The Problem ;

1. OnStartCommand is not meant to be coded the long running procedures / statements of code..
2. Nor it is meant to be coded at all........

### The Solution;

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d("RUNNER : ", "\nPERFORMING....");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Above single line tells android to keep alive **ALL THE TIME UNTIL DEVELOPER STOPS IT ON HIS OWN VIA CODE STOPSELF** Even removed from `background` or from `recents`; It gets re-created automatically by android os

> Then where should i write the code.... ??

Wait... its too early to code yet....!!! patience

> begins long running task that **analyzes** and **checks device** and **app status**

Your question is un clear and in my brain there is a gradle error ... `I can not resolve your symbols` :

1. analyzes
2. checks device
3. app status

But i know that these your broadcasts definitely .. And you need to implement broadcast-receivers... to receive it...!!

> I will implement Broadcast receivers... Its too easy...

### The Problem ;

Wait... Android O do not allows you to implement many broadcast receivers from static receivers like we does... And even we are not allowed to call that receivers on specific intent-actions from manifest.xml

### The Solution;

Implement runtime receivers in your above created service `YourLongRunningService` in `onCreate` like :

```
IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter();
myFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
this.registerReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver, CallFilter);
```

CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is an example and it would be your intent action / broadcast you want to listen for...!!

> What is `mCallBroadcastReceiver` and all...

These are runtime registration of receivers... and needed to be unregistered from `onDestroy` like :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    this.unregisterReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

> No.... No... No.... I do not want to un-register it... I want it always working..

Our service is `START_STICKY` Even if it is destroyed; gets started automatically and registers `mCallBroadcastReceiver` in `onCreate` again..

> Where is the receiver then....???

In this case `mCallBroadcastReceiver` is receiver defined in class area where we declares the variables and constants :

```
public class YourLongRunningService extends Service
{
NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1";

private BroadcastReceiver mCallBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      // All your receiver code goes here...
    }
};

// your constructor

// your onStartcommand
// your ondestroy
}
```

> What notification Manager is doing here....???

In and above O you can not run foreground service without proper `Ongoing` task notification... It will go in your `onCreate` which will call Startforeground with the notification to start this service as a foreground service

> What below android O...?

It works below Android O too... Just call with normal startservice its code it given on very start...!!

> Where is my long running code goes then....???

From receiver receive broadcast you want and start a `intentservice` or a `job` or a alarm class or whatever you want...

> I will make a simple class which takes `context` in constructor and defines a public method named `LongRunningCode` may be of one crore lines of code....
>   And on receiving broadcast in receiver , I will make a object of that class by passing `context` of receiver and will simply call `LongRunningCode` method with that `object`

Hope it helps